# Conflict between $(document).ready and prototype.js

Tags: jquery, html, prototypejs, document-ready

I have this problem with `prototype.js` when I include `$(document).ready`
in my webpage it doesn't work.

Here is part of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/scripts/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
  function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';    
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sendmail2').on('submit', function(){
      alert('Ok');
    });
  });           
</script>
```

But when I remove prototype the script works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change all "$" with extended name "jQuery"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: are you including jQuery BEFORE prototype? This in addition to use "jQuery" in place of "$"

Answer (score 0):

**[Putting jQuery Into No-Conflict Mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#putting-jquery-into-no-conflict-mode)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready
```